Bash Script for Replacing Playlist Lines
(Just when I think I can script a shell program).
Need to convert m3u files written in Windows to Linux file type.
Because well (think most would agree that MediaMonkey does a lot better job than any Linux app for generating playlists. But the whole backslash thing. And I live by Arch for most everything. I know many way to approach, but...
Here is my Simple Script (Which does nothing):
#! /bin/bash

c=1
loadfile=$HOME/Music/M3U/loadfile.m3u
newfile=$HOME/Music/M3U/newfile.m3u

strOldPath='Z:\'
strNewPath='/media/Media/'
strBSlash='\'
strFSlash='/'

while read line; do
  for i in $loadfile; do
    sed "s/$OldPath/$NewPath/g"
    sed "s/$BSlash/$FSlash/g"

    echo "$line"
    c=$(( c + 1 ))
  done

done

And here is a sample loadfile:
#EXTM3U
Z:\My Music\Peter Gabriel\1989 - Passion (lossless)\08 - Zaar.flac
Z:\My Music\Peter Gabriel\1990 - Shaking The Tree (lossless)\15 - Zaar.flac
Z:\My Music\Mozart\Amadeus Soundtrack\Disc 2\13 - Zaide Aria - Ruhe Sanft.mp3
Z:\My Music\Billy Joel\1978 - 52nd Street (lossless)\04 - Zanzibar.flac

Gotta be something simple I'm missing here.

Replace / in your sed commands so it doesn't clash with your patterns.

See Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed.

please update the question with the (correct) expected result

I knew it was an escape char issue. but solution maybe not as simple as it should. I think I'm going to crack open a powershell and try the 'replace' function. Have to go to back to my real job now but will check back in a bit.

Assumptions:

OP wishes to convert Windows paths to UNIX/Linux paths

There are several issues with the current script:

typo in variable names, eg, strOldPath is defined but incorrectly referenced as $OldPath
the while read loop is not given any input (I'd expect OP's current script to just hang due to the while read loop waiting for input)
the sed calls are given no input
the for i in $loadfile appears to be an attempt to read lines from $loadfile but this construct does not actually really lines from the file
I'm assuming the while read and for i in $loadfile are both attempting to read lines from $loadfile in which case there's no need for the duplicate processes to read from the same file
the sed calls do not modify $line so the final echo $line is just going to repeat the original input to the while read loop (assuming the while read loop has been updated to read data from $loadfile)
since the patterns to be processed by sed contain forward slashes (/) it will be necessary to either escape the forward slashes (in the patterns) or provide sed with a different script delimiter that doesn't appear in the patterns (eg, #)
a backslash has special meaning to sed as an escape code; to process a literal backslash it will be necessary to escape it (ie, replace each \ with \\ in the patterns)
at no point is any output written to $newfile so even if all of the previous issues are addressed the script (still) will not populate $newfile with any content

Pulling this all together the following should generate the desired results:
$ cat testme
#!/bin/bash 

loadfile=load_file
newfile=new_file

strOldPath='Z:\\'                     # escape each backslash
strNewPath='/media/Media/'
strBSlash='\\'                        # escape each backslash
strFSlash='/'

while read -r line; do
    sed "s#${strOldPath}#${strNewPath}#g" <<< "${line}" | sed "s#${strBSlash}#${strFSlash}#g"
#or sed "s#${strOldPath}#${strNewPath}#g; s#${strBSlash}#${strFSlash}#g" <<< "${line}"
done < "${loadfile}" > "${newfile}"

NOTE: the variable c is not actually used anywhere in OP's script so I've removed it
Taking for a test Drive:
$ ./testme

$ cat new_file
#EXTM3U
/media/Media/My Music/Peter Gabriel/1989 - Passion (lossless)/08 - Zaar.flac
/media/Media/My Music/Peter Gabriel/1990 - Shaking The Tree (lossless)/15 - Zaar.flac
/media/Media/My Music/Mozart/Amadeus Soundtrack/Disc 2/13 - Zaide Aria - Ruhe Sanft.mp3
/media/Media/My Music/Billy Joel/1978 - 52nd Street (lossless)/04 - Zanzibar.flac

Since sed is capable of working on an entire file there's no need for the while read loop. Using the single compound sed script we now have:
$ cat testme2
#!/bin/bash 

loadfile=load_file
newfile=new_file

strOldPath='Z:\\'
strNewPath='/media/Media/'
strBSlash='\\'
strFSlash='/'

sed "s#${strOldPath}#${strNewPath}#g; s#${strBSlash}#${strFSlash}#g" "${loadfile}" > "${newfile}"

Taking for test drive:
$ ./testme2

$ cat new_file
#EXTM3U
/media/Media/My Music/Peter Gabriel/1989 - Passion (lossless)/08 - Zaar.flac
/media/Media/My Music/Peter Gabriel/1990 - Shaking The Tree (lossless)/15 - Zaar.flac
/media/Media/My Music/Mozart/Amadeus Soundtrack/Disc 2/13 - Zaide Aria - Ruhe Sanft.mp3
/media/Media/My Music/Billy Joel/1978 - 52nd Street (lossless)/04 - Zanzibar.flac


Since the input file appears to be coming from a Windows environment OP may want to keep an eye out for possible issues with Windows/DOS line endings (\r\n) in the new file.
If applications have a problem processing the new file consider removing the \r characters to see if that addresses the issue, eg, dos2unix "${newfile}".

Thank you so much. Derp! on the var $OldPath. Um I went the lazy way and just did a find replace IDE. But for the future want to automate via script. again THX!
